# Do you live in a bakery?

Tags: riddle, word

- I have the shape of a doughnut.
- I have the texture of a croissant.
- I have the appearance of a wedding cake.

---

You use me everyday.
What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are

> A roll of toilet paper

> I have the shape of a doughnut.

> Viewed from the side, a roll of toilet paper looks like a doughnut

> I have the texture of a croissant.

> A croissant is layered, just like a roll of toilet paper

> I have the appearance of a wedding cake.

> A wedding cake is white, has beautiful imprints, and is cylindrical just like a roll of toilet paper

> You use me everyday.

> Who doesn't?

Comment: You've got it! .

Answer (score 6):

You are

> the universe.

> I have the shape of a doughnut.

> [Scientists theorize that the universe is doughnut-shaped (sort of).](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-torus_model_of_the_universe)

> I have the texture of a croissant.

> [*Croissant* in French means "increasing" or "growing"](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/croissant#French), and [the universe is believed to be expanding](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_the_universe).

> I have the appearance of a wedding cake

> — [layered](http://archeology.uark.edu/indiansofarkansas/printerfriendly.html?pageName=The%20Three-Layer%20Universe) and [festooned with decorations](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html).

> You use me everyday.

> Every time I breath or eat or move I'm using the universe.

Comment: I don't see how it fits the "You use me everyday" part, but +1 - like the answer

Comment: @TCooper, I'll edit it in.

Comment: Sorry, not the answer

Comment: *Two* scientists proposed that about the universe.

Answer (score 2):

YOU are a

> TIRE

> Tires have the shape of a doughnut

> Tires inflate and deflate

> Tires with a tube look like cakes

> Tires of all kinds are used every day.

Comment: Sorry, not the answer.

Comment: check your spelling on your suggested answer :)

Comment: @nr_aus I believe this is a regional spelling difference so while I wouldn't have spelt it this way I assume this is the correct spelling where that user is (or even if not it is still a correct spelling in some places).

Comment: I don't see how a tire has the appearance of a wedding cake. A wedding cake is usually light in color and dainty, whereas a tire is black and rough,

Comment: I have seen tires of different colors and wedding cakes in variety of dark colors.

Comment: @VassilisParassidis Yes, anything can exist, but I'm talking about most of the things.

Comment: cheers for informing me of the alternate spelling. The relevance of the '85% of the english speaking population' comment is pointless, you could have just said 'in the US/Cananda'.

Answer (score 2):

You are

> Red blood cells

> I have the shape of a doughnut.

> Red blood cells are [shaped like a donut](https://img.favpng.com/24/6/10/red-blood-cell-hemoglobin-png-favpng-4gJK9SnxCLkQzxJLfVQgtnh6a.jpg).

> I have the texture of a croissant.

> Red blood cells are flexible, like a croissant, in order to penetrate the smallest blood vessels.

> I have the appearance of a wedding cake

> Often red blood cells are [stacked](https://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large-5/red-blood-cell-rouleaux-scientificanimationscom--science-photo-library.jpg) giving the appearance of a wedding cake.

> You use me everyday.

> Every living human being use their own red blood cells all the time.

Comment: Nice, but I don't see how one can call something like a croissant only because it's soft.

Comment: Well, texture means "*the feel, appearance, or consistency (of something)*", and *softness* is closer to that definition than *layered* ;-)

Comment: Well, then does that mean that red blood cells have the texture of donuts and cakes as well?